# PHP regular expression to replace content inside of brackets

Tags: php

I'm working on a "shortcode" functionality to replace content in text saved in the database.

I am trying to find all occurrences of anything inside of double brackets `{{ }}`, see if a replacement exists, and if so, replace it. I'm bad on regex and I don't know if this is the most efficient way of doing this:

```
$string = "This is a {{test}} to see if it {{works}}";
$regex = ""; // Unfortunately, I'm clueless when it comes to regex

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

$replacements = array(
    'test' => 'sample',
    'works' => 'exists'
);

foreach ($matches as $match) {

    if (array_key_exists($match, $replacements)) {  
        $string = str_replace($match, $replacements[$match], $string);          
    }

}

return $string;
```

In this example, I would like to return:

`This is a sample to see if it exists`

I'd like to make provision for if the "shortcode" doesn't exist, to just simply leave it in the content as-is.

Comment: You can test your expressions [here](https://regex101.com/). However if your replacements are as simple as in the example then use `str_replace()` (just concat braces to needles). Otherwise I'd use `preg_replace_callback()` in this case.

Comment: this is regex `'/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/`

Comment: @JROB if this is for processing shortcodes purpose, you can use my Shortcode library: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode with default handler and custom Syntax object that will detect and replace everything according to the desired array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$string = "This is a {{test}} to see if it {{works}}";
$regex  = "|\{\{(.*)\}\}|"; 

$replacements = [
'test' => 'sample',
'works' => 'exists'
];

preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) use($replacemnets) {
  if (isset($replacements[$matches[0]]) {
     return $replacements[$matches[0];
  }
  else {
     return $matches[0];
  }
}, $string);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know in advance the keywords enclosed in double braces you don't even need regular expressions. A simple call to [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is enough:

```
$string = "This is a {{test}} to see if it {{works}}";

$replacements = array(
    '{{test}}' => 'sample',
    '{{works}}' => 'exists',
);

$text = str_replace(array_keys($replacements), array_values($replacements), $string);
```

But if you want to replace all the keywords, even those you don't have a replacement for, the regular expressions are unavoidable and the function [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) comes to the rescue:

```
$string = "This is a {{test}} to see if it {{works}}";

$replacements = array(
    '{{test}}' => 'sample',
    '{{works}}' => 'exists',
);

$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\{\{[^}]*\}\}/',
    function (array $m) use ($replacements) {
        return array_key_exists($m[0], $replacements) ? $replacements[$m[0]] : '';
    },
    $string
);
```

Because `{` and `}` are [special characters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) in regular expressions, they need to be [escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) in order to be interpreted as normal characters (and ignore their special meaning).

The [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (the callback) is invoked every time the regex matches a part of the string. `$m[0]` always contains the part of the string that matches the entire regex. If the regex contains [subpatterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php), the string parts that match each of the subpatterns are available in `$m` at various positions. There is no subpattern in the expression we use, `$m` contains a single value at index `0`.

The value returned by the callback is used as replacement for the part of the string that matches the entire expression.