# How to replace string used multiple time between same 2 characters?

Tags: php, regex

I have this text.
**My Name is (Name). I live in (Turkey).**

I would like to replace whatever is in brackets with the input tag.
Desired Output should be like :

My Name is **INPUT TAG HERE**. I live in **INPUT TAG HERE**.

Comment: you have your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334314/php-regular-expression-to-replace-content-inside-of-brackets

Comment: @melvin The answer is not exactly the same, because the OP wants replace whatever between brackets by the same string. In your link it's a bit more complicated, he replaces each string by a different string.

Comment: @AnthonyB. Good one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular expression to replace content inside of brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334314/php-regular-expression-to-replace-content-inside-of-brackets)

Comment: @Haem Please see my comments, the need is not the same. In your link the need is more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:-

```
<?php
$string = 'My Name is (Name some). I live in (Turkey).';
// this pattern takes care of white spaces in multi word keywords inside () also
$pattern = '(\([\w\s]+\)*)';
$replacement = 'INPUT TAG HERE';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

OUTPUT:-
    My Name is INPUT TAG HERE. I live in INPUT TAG HERE.

this pattern takes care of white spaces in multi word keywords inside () also

Comment: It's good to think about the white spaces. But it doesn't allow all chars, and the OP wants to replace `whatever between brackets`. If for any reason he puts an `{` between its brackets the string will not be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code :

```
<?php
//Allow **all** characters except parenthesis
$regex = '/\([^\(\)]+\)/';
//The matching items will be replaced by this
$replacement = 'INPUT TAG HERE';
//Input string
$sentence = 'My Name is (Name). I live in (Turkey).';
echo preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $sentence);
```

Will output:

```
My Name is INPUT TAG HERE. I live in INPUT TAG HERE.
```

This code uses the [preg_replace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) method to replace the strings using a regular expression.
All characters are allowed between brackets (spaces, letters, digits, whatever else), absolutely all except other parenthesis.