# Replace random values with specific values in order in a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

Let's say I have a the following string:

```
{{Hi}}, This {{is}} {{Debby}}.
```

I want to replace the text inside `{{ANYTHING}}` with variables passed to a function. For example, if the function is `change_values('Hola', 'was', 'Antonio')`.

The result would be:

```
Hola, This was Antonio.
```

First word or character surrounded by `{{}}` was replaced by the first parameter of `change_values()`. Similarly, the second word or character was replaced by the second parameter and so on.

To be clear, the values `Hi`, `is` and `Debby` can change. The passed parameters can also change. The only thing that is consistent is that First `{{}}` would be replaced by first parameter and so on.

I was planning on using `str_replace()` originally but the text keepschanging each time. I also thought about using `regex` but cannot figure out how to do the replacements sequentially.

Any help would be appreciated.

A few more examples,

```
{{Fiona}} is a lucky {{girl}}.
```

will become

```
Mike is a lucky man.
```

I am using `{{}}` as identifiers in the original string to make it easy to figure out what needs to be replaced. If this can create an issue, I am open to other (better) solutions.

Comment: [Here is an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334314/php-regular-expression-to-replace-content-inside-of-brackets) if you can define the find and replace values as an associative array.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew I will give it a try. :)

Comment: There is one problem, it kind of fixes the values in original string using an associative array.

Comment: You could try [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php), check out Example #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP5.6 or later, this function will do what you want. It uses [`...`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) to pack all the replacements into an array, and then [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace all the strings surrounded by `{{` and `}}` with the replacements. By using the `limit` parameter to `preg_replace`, we prevent the pattern replacing all the `{{}}` strings with the first value in the `replacements` array.

```
function change_values($string, ...$replacements) {
    return preg_replace(array_fill(0, count($replacements), '/{{[^}]+}}/'), $replacements, $string, 1);
}
echo change_values('{{Hi}}, This {{is}} {{Debby}}.', 'Hola', 'was', 'Antonio');
echo change_values('{{Fiona}} is a lucky {{girl}}.', 'Mike', 'man');
```

Output:

```
Hola, This was Antonio.
Mike is a lucky man.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $input = '{{Fiona}} is a lucky {{girl}}.';
    $replaceArray = ['Mike', 'man'];
    $expectedOut = 'Mike is a lucky man.';

    preg_match_all('/({{\w+}})/', $input,$matches);
    $out = str_replace($matches[0], $replaceArray, $input);

    if($out === $expectedOut){
        print_r($out);
    }
```